# Set email BCC with CURL

Tags: bash, curl, smtp

I only see ways to set multiple recipients, what if I want to BCC some recipients, how would I accomplish that in Curl? Google searching, I'm surprisingly not coming up with anything.

Here's what my command currently looks like. I'm sending from `$from_email` to emails: `$to_email_1` and `$to_email_2`.

```
curl -s "$url" \
     --mail-from "$from_email" \
     --mail-rcpt "$to_email_1" \
     --mail-rcpt "$to_email_2" \
     --ssl \
     -T "email_content.txt"
```

Let's say I want to BCC `$to_email_2`. How would I accomplish that with Curl?

Comment: Since BCC just means that this is a receiver, which does not show up in the mail heade, I think you just need to **not** generate a Cc header for `$to_email_2`. See [here](https://skeletonkey.com/filemaker-18-smtp-curl/) and [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/curl-examples/#sending-a-basic-email-to-multiple-recipients)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!